# Error while saving a standalone application

Tags: android, windows, livecode

I have reached a problem in the final stages of completing my stack. I have been working on this project for a couple months now and it is finally complete. The aim of the app is for you (as the user) to be able to have a type of calculator which performs a certain sequence of sums once a numerical value is entered. It is now finished (thank goodness! :P) but I have reached an error whilst saving this app. I am saving it as an Android application (.apk) for use on a mobile phone. I have the Android personal 1 pack, and my error is as follows:

> There was an error while saving the standalone application could not compile application class

I am unsure as to why this is occurring but find it hard to believe that this could have occurred because of either invalid syntax or that a command I was using was incompatible with Android.

As I said before my stack is very simple and only performs a few basic mathematical functions (mainly multiplying contents of fields) by each other. If you wish to see this script, please request.

Comment: This is Stack Overflow, when you think you should _maybe_ post code, it's generally good to do so. That way experts can browse it over and their intuition will eliminate that potential concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NinjaBunny,

This sounds more like an error from the Android SDK than a LiveCode error. For starters check these things in the Android settings pane in the LiveCode Standalone Applications Settings:

Identifier: It has to be unique to this application. If you've ever done a test build for Android without changing this default identifier you will get an error.

Signing: Unless you have a key, choose Sign for development only or Don't sign.

Minimum Android version: make sure you have all of the packages needed for your target version in your Android SDK.

[image: LiveCode Android settings]

Comment: Great thanks haven't got the Android SDK set up in preferences! THX :D

Comment: Is there any difference between "Sign for development only" or "Don't sign"?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if there is a practical difference if you are just creating APKs for testing purposes.

Comment: Well I am not planning on going fully commercial but I am hoping to be able to install it onto a phone for personal use.

Comment: Currently, I often have this error. It appears that the preferences window keeps losing the path to the Android folder.

Answer (score 1):

@ninjabunny14 yep it's a good idea to include code, actual text of error messages, details of the platform you're developing on, versions of LiveCode/Android etc

In the meantime you could Google "error while saving the standalone application could not compile application class" like I've just done and found quite a few links to LiveCode forum threads (like this one http://forums.runrev.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=12330) which look like they might be of use...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit/Preferences and set up the Android SDK path, which is probably empty in your case:

[image: LiveCode Preferences]

Answer (score 0):

I had this a few times because it is easy to forget.
The identifier in the android settings does not like characters like - so do not use a name like com.itis-me.myapp , but use com.itisme.myapp

the use of a character like - gives you this error.